# Convert datetime in dataframe to seconds

Tags: pandas, datetime, normal-distribution

Below is the output of `[mydataframe].info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
receivedtime    1000 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
```

The data is in this format -

```
0  2018-08-18 14:24:59.783
1  2018-08-18 14:24:32.227
```

I don't care about the date. I just want to convert the time to seconds (UTC). Below is what I want -

```
   seconds 
0  1534734768 
1  1534734769
```

Following is what I have tried so far,

**strptime()**

```
strptime() argument 1 must be str, not DataFrame
```

**pd.to_datetime(df)**

```
to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

The reason I am trying to do this is because I am trying to run the D’Agostino’s K^2 Test like so `stat, p = normaltest(df)` and I keep getting `ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('<M8[ns]')` error. So I am hoping once I convert this into seconds, I will stop getting that error.

Comment: What is the output expected for this input?

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_timedelta(df['your-col']).dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: Use `pd.to_timedelta(df['col']).dt.total_seconds()`